# Problems with implementing a sorted map

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, hashmap

I'm trying to implement a sorted hash map and I have one problem. Let me describe the situation first, so that one will understand what's going on.

I defined an interface called `Map`. It looks like this

```
public interface Map<K extends Comparable<K>, V>  {
        /*** STATE INFORMATION ***/
public boolean isEmpty();
public int size();
public boolean contains(K key);
        /*** MAIN OPERATIONS ***/
public void insert(K key, V value);
public V get(K key);
public V delete(K key);
```

}

And I also defined a class called `SortedMap` which implements this interface. In this class I have a nested static class called `Item` which acts as wrapper. Here it is

```
private static class Item<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<Item<K, V>> {
    private K key;
    private V value;

    Item(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.format("%s=%s", key.toString(), value.toString()); }

    public int compareTo(Item<K, V> item) {
        if (key.compareTo(item.key) > 0) return 1;
        else if (key.compareTo(item.key) < 0) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

And to store objects of this class I use a red black BST as an underlying storage system.

```
private RedBlackBST<Item<K, V>> storage = new RedBlackBST<>();
```

My red black BST can store only one item (`Item<K, V>` in this case) per node, which itself stores two others.

```
public final class RedBlackBST<T extends Comparable<T>> {
private Node<T> root;
.........
// All the rest of it
}
```

As you all know a map cannot have duplicate keys, so in my `insert()` method I first have to check whether it already contains that key and when I delegate this task to my red black BST `storage.contains()` I can't pass it a key only, I have to pass `Item`. This is where the problem arises. 
Is there a way to solve this problem without creating yet another red black tree that might look something like this `Tree<K, V>`?

Comment: What's wrong with [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)? And - by the way - there is no data structure like a _sorted hash map_.

Comment: Can you modify `RedBlackBST` class so that `contains` method accepts a key only?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes, I know that there is no sorted hash map since a hash map uses an array as an underlying storage system. There is no any problems with `TreeMap` but in my case I want to implement my own sorted map  from scratch.

Comment: @DanilGaponov unfortunately I can't. My `contains()` method in `RedBlackBST` accepts `T` which is `Item<K, V>`. Here is my entire
[class](https://github.com/RenatKaitmazov/Data-Structures/blob/master/datastr/tree/RedBlackBST)

Comment: @RenatKaitmazov If you want to be able to test for a specific key in your storage, than you will have to implement such a method. You can also try to test for an item with your key and any value, your comparator should return 0 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that a `Map`, cannot have duplicate key but you don't have to call `contains()` in your `insert()`. Actually in JDK, the behavior of the `insert()` equivalent method - `put()` is that if key already exists it's replaced with the new key.
So what you can do is to assume that the key is unique and new and go on to insert it. If somehow in the place you want to store you find a key already exists there then you can either replace the corresponding value; or you can throw an exception, depends on what's your desired behavior.

There already is a `SortedMap` interface in JDK and a `TreeMap` whose implementation is based on a Red Black Tree.

Comment: If a particular key is already in `storage`, I'd like `insert()` method to replace the old value with a new one just like JDK `TreeMap` does it. But I haven't come up with a solution to it so far.